# Bootstrap collapse when I click one only this will expand and rest of them will auto hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I click more it expands well. But I want to hide rest of collapse when I click another one. Here is my source code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="first">
    <p>hidden content hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">More</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="second">
    <p>hidden content hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#second">More</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="third">
    <p>hidden content hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#third">More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Bootstrap's [Accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) instead of single Collapse.

Comment: Sorry I don't want to use Accordion due to my total structure will have to change. Is it possible by using only collapse and some of Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add a short jQuery code, which take advantage of Bootstrap's methods and events:

```
$('.content').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
   $(this).siblings().children().collapse('hide');
});
```

Below you can check a working example out:

```js
$('.content').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).siblings().children().collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="first">
    <p>hidden content hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#first">More</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="second">
    <p>hidden content hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#second">More</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>content content content content content</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="third">
    <p>hidden content hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#third">More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I expect exactly this one.

Comment: Your welcome. Make use of Bootstrap events and methods is easest way to accomplish certain things.